# How to lookup an Enum by value?

Tags: typescript, enums

I have an enum with a bunch of API messages I have translated to show on the front-end:

```
export enum API_MESSAGES {
  FAILED_TO_LOAD = 'Failed to load data',
  TOKEN_INVALID = 'Token seems to be invalid',
}
```

I would like to use the error coming from the back-end to get the translated value:

```
onError: (error: AxiosError<ApiError>) => {
  const errorRes = error.response?.data.error;
  console.log(API_MESSAGES[errorRes])
}
```

However this throws the following TS error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof API_MESSAGES'

No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof API_MESSAGES'
```

I have tried searching but I didn't find an easy way to access the enum.

Comment: Use class instead of enum and change it to object.

export class API_MESSAGES {
  FAILED_TO_LOAD : 'Failed to load data',
  TOKEN_INVALID :'Token seems to be invalid',
}

Comment: What should happen if `error.response?.data.error` _isn't_ one of the keys in `API_MESSAGES`?

Comment: I know the error.response?.data.error could fail, I will be be adding a fallback for it

Comment: So I have worked out by inference that your back-end does not use the Enum definition, that it is sending `FAILED_TO_LOAD` and `TOKEN_INVALID` as actual codes. Then Enums don't make sense for this: (1) they are program-level named constants, not wire-level values and (2) type-safety doesn't make sense/is not enforced since the back-end isn't using the same Enum def.  Instead use a mapping object. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### string enums do not support reverse mappings

`API_MESSAGES[errorRes]` results in an error because, per the [Typescript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings):

> #### Reverse mappings
>
> In addition to creating an object with property names for members, numeric enums members also get a reverse mapping from enum values to enum names.

A numeric enum is

> compiled into an object that stores both forward (name -> value) and reverse (value -> name) mappings.

> Keep in mind that string enum members do not get a reverse mapping generated at all.

### but you don't want a reverse mapping anyway!

Your goal is to display the "translated" (human friendly) API message. So even if `API_MESSAGES[errorRes]` was supported for string enums, you would be doing this:

```
'Token seems to be invalid' --> TOKEN_INVALID
```

i.e. the opposite of what you want.

### ***If*** your back-end is using the same enum definition, it would be sending the "translated" value already!

Assuming your back-end code is using the same `API_MESSAGES` enum, then really all it is doing is using "[a set of named constants](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)", e.g. `FAILED_TO_LOAD` and `TOKEN_INVALID`, whose values ***are the translated messages themselves***.

In other words, if your back-end is simply serializing the `API_MESSAGES` in its response to the front-end, it is sending the "translated" message already.

Which means your `onError` function would just be:

```
onError: (error: AxiosError<ApiError>) => {
  const errorRes = error.response?.data.error;
  console.log(errorRes)
}
```

From the Typescript perspective and what your logic implies, `error.response?.data.error` has the type `API_MESSAGES`. Because Typescript enums are really just named constants, what this means is that `error.response?.data.error` would effectively be the following union type

```
type API_MESSAGES = 'Failed to load data' | 'Token seems to be invalid',
```

So again, you would *already* have the translated value. `FAILED_TO_LOAD` and `TOKEN_INVALID` would be just the Typescript *names* for those values. ***If your back-end is using the same enum definition.***

### ***If*** your back-end is sending codes, you simply need a mapping object

If `FAILED_TO_LOAD` and `TOKEN_INVALID` are the actual message strings being sent by the backend, you just need [a mapping object instead of an enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums):

```js
export const API_MESSAGES = {
  FAILED_TO_LOAD = 'Failed to load data',
  TOKEN_INVALID = 'Token seems to be invalid',
} as const;

// type API_MESSAGE = 'FAILED_TO_LOAD' | 'TOKEN_INVALID'
export type API_MESSAGE = keyof typeof API_MESSAGES
```

The error code coming across the wire from the backend is
just a plain string, not a typed Enum. This `convertServerMessage`
function demonstrates how to validate and convert it to the `API_MESSAGE` enum. [As you said earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70276775/access-a-typescript-enum-with-a-variable-value/70277735?noredirect=1#comment124230981_70276775), this is something you have
to do somewhere. You probably won't need this separate method -- Instead you can just put its logic in that part of your code that reads the server response and constructs the AxiosError object,  whose `AxiosError.response.data.error` should have the type `API_MESSAGE`.

```js
export function convertServerMessage(msg: string): API_MESSAGE {
    if (msg in API_MESSAGES) {
        return msg as API_MESSAGE
    } else {
        // error logic goes here
    }
}
```

then your original `onError` will work as you wanted (see note at bottom):

```js
onError: (error: AxiosError<ApiError>) => {
    // as I said above, the conversion from string code to 
    // enum should probably happen elsewere. I have it here
    // to keep the example simple.
    const errorRes = convertServerMessage(error.response?.data.error);
    console.log(API_MESSAGES[errorRes])
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works! I still got one of the initial TS warnings: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 

But this is solved by adding export const API_MESSAGES: { [key: string]: string } = {

Comment: @Ronald... The warning is due to a mistake on my part in my example! I just fixed it. See the correct type declaration for type API_MESSAGE above, and the  comment about the `convertServerMessage`.  This would be a more typesafe than your fix, which basically accepts any string.   Let me know if that makes everything perfect by upvoting my answer (usually you should both upvote and accept an answer that works for you )

Comment: Thanks a lot! this works indeed, and I have upvoted and accepted the answer now.